# Automatize text in an email from R

Tags: r

I was looking how to send emails from R, but I want to know how to automatize text depending on a table like this one:

```
  Name       Email              CODE
  <chr>      <chr>             <dbl>
1 Student 1  mail@example.com     30
2 Student 2  mail2@example.com    20
3 Student 20 mail3@example.com     5
```

For example, I would like to send different messages with different text depending on the student's names and codes:

```
Hello Student 20,
your code is 5.

See you.
```

And the same with Student 1, Student 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
sprintf("Hello %s your code is %d", df$name, df$code)
[1] "Hello x your code is 12" "Hello y your code is 32"

glue::glue_data(df, "Hello {name} your code is {code}")
Hello x your code is 12
Hello y your code is 32
```

Data

```
df = data.frame(name = c('x', 'y'), code = c(12, 32))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` to add line breaks and have a better formatted text.

E.g. with `paste0`

```
msgs <- paste0("Hello ", df$name, ",\nyour code is: ", df$code, ".\n\nSee you.\n")
msgs
## [1] "Hello x,\nyour code is: 12.\n\nSee you.\n"
## [2] "Hello y,\nyour code is: 32.\n\nSee you.\n"
```

To see how it will look like you can use `cat`, here is the first message:

```
cat(msgs[1])

Hello x,
your code is: 12.

See you.
```